# Check CSV for 2 rows with the same text & time within 60mins

Tags: php, csv, datetime

I am looping through a CSV file with the following structure

```
text,time
"Hey you",20181219T15:59:00
"Hey you",20181219T15:39:00
"Random",20181219T15:39:00
```

This simply contains a 'text string' and another string that represents an ISO 8601 date.

I want to perform a function that will check if a) it has found two rows with the **exact** same text & has the timeframe between these is within 60 minutes?

Can anyone suggest the best way to approach this (taking into account the CSV will be a max of 50 entries so want to make this as efficient as possible.

So my array returned looks like this once the dates are parsed via DateTime

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [text] => Hey you
        [time] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-12-19 15:59:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/London
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [text] => Hey you
        [time] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2018-12-19 15:39:00.000000
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => Europe/London
            )

    )
)
```

What would be the best method to check for the exact same text **AND** time is within one hour of the same text?

Comment: can you have "hey you", "another text", "hey you"? and are those records ordered by time or random or by text?

Comment: @LelioFaieta it could have various text strings - but will only consider a match that has the exact same string and date within one hour

Comment: you are not answering my questions... i am asking about what is the structure of the **input** not how the **output** should look like

Comment: the structure of the input is as per the csv in the original post - yes it is possible to have "hey you", "another text", "hey you" on three lines this isn't ordered by anything it just goes loop through the csv one line at a time - does that help explain the input structure better - please let me know if it doesn't

Comment: I would group those by the texts to begin with (use that as key of an associative array), and put all the dates for that text into an array under that key. After you read all the data, sort those dates, and then go through them checking the difference from one to the next …

Comment: @Zabs it does help. You first then have to order by text and then order by date keeping the text ordering first. Then you can see the time difference between each pair

Comment: @LelioFaieta yeah i see what you mean now thanks mate :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the array is ordered by Datetime (so bigger key means newer date time), you can do as follow:

```
// set an array to track text we meet
$textList = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $element){
    $text = $element['text'];
    if (!array_key_exists($text, $textList)) {
        // first time we meet this text, we track it and its position in the array
        $textList[$text] = $key;
    }else{
        // second time we meet this test, we compare the current date time with the previous one to get difference in minutes
        $currentTime = $element['time'];
        $previousTimeKey = $textList[$text];
        $previousTime = $array[$previousTimeKey]['time'];
        $diff = $currentTime->diff($previousTime);
        // total minutes of diff: hours*60 + minutes
        $diffInMinutes = $diff->format('%h') * 60 + $diff->format('%i');
        if ($diffInMinutes < 60) {
            // do whatever you need.. 
        }
    }
}
```

Complicate this for your particular needs. ;)

PS if the array is not ordered by date time, consider to order it before and then use this function: the algorithm with an array not ordered by date time would be much harder.

Answer (score 1):

Tried this with your given array
My solution with the time difference might not be pretty but i noticed the other answer doesn't take days/months/years into the time difference so it will pass if the date is different but time of the day is less than 60minutes.

This also worked no matter if the first date is older or younger, so the array sorting isn't needed.

```
function findMatch($arrays){
$tmp_list = []; //takes the first occurance of text
foreach ($arrays as $key => $array) {

        if(isset($tmp_list[$array['text']])){
            //possible match check for time difference
            $difference = $tmp_list[$array['text']]->diff($array['time']);

            if($difference->y === 0 && $difference->m === 0 && $difference->d === 0 && $difference->h === 0 && $difference->i <= 59 && $difference->s <= 59){
                //less than hour difference
            }else{
                //more than hour difference
            }


        }else{
            $tmp_list[$array['text']] = $array['time'];
        }   

}
}

findMatch($arrays);
```